# Initializing class/struct from a void pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, memory-pool

I have a memory pool that is allocated as char*. When I want to create an object I request memory from that pool that returns a char* somewhere in that pool cast to a void*.

So when I create a object I do this

```
Data* poolTest = (Data*)pool->GetMemory(sizeof(Data));
```

But this does not allow me to access the constructor of the class Data and I have to assign the value after I create it.

Is there anyway to change this to allow me to pass arguments the same way I would do with

```
Data* test = new Data(5, 5, 5);
```

Not sure if it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems *placement new* is what you are looking for. Basically you give it raw memory, and create objects with dynamic storage duration in the provided memory region. Managing the lifetimes of the memory region and created objects is up to you, of course.

Example from the docs:

> ```
> char* ptr = new char[sizeof(T)]; // allocate memory
> T* tptr = new(ptr) T;            // construct in allocated storage ("place")
> tptr->~T();                      // destruct
> delete[] ptr;                    // deallocate memory
> ```

For reference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Possibly `std::uninitialized_fill()` can also fit your use case:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill

If you have access to C++17 features, also have a look at `std::uninitialized_default_construct()` and `std::uninitialized_value_construct()`:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct

Maybe you should consider writing an allocator to wrap your memory pool:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator

Comment: Awesome the first exampled worked a charm but I will look into the other links as well! Thanks!